# Creating a report via reading from a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a 'side project' in school that quizzes users and then saves their results into a report (csv file). So far, I've made one report where the 'customer' I'm making the quiz for (Fergus) can search for a specific user and see their progress in quizzes they've done and that's gone fine, but I'm struggling with the second report.

For the second report, Fergus has to enter the topic of a certain subject (maths, english, science, etc) and a difficulty level (easy, hard, etc) and it SHOULD spit out a report stating the average score achieved on this quiz. I tried to find the average via adding up all of the individual scores and then diving it by the amount of times people have taken that particular quiz, but there seems to be an issue when reading the file as it is just reading all the results as zero. Meaning that when the overall score is about to be divided by the number of times the quiz has been taken, it shows up with an error saying I tried to divide by zero.

```
def quizReport():
    overall=0
    amount=0
    subjectInput=input("\nPlease enter the subject name of the quiz(zes) you wish to view: ")
    difficultyInput=input("Please enter the difficulty level of the quiz(zes) you wish to view: ")
    with open ('reportForFergusTwo.csv') as quizzReport:
        quizReportReader=csv.reader(quizzReport)
        for column in quizReportReader:
            if subjectInput == column[0]:
                if difficultyInput == column[1]:
                    if ('0') == column[2]:
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('1') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+1
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('2') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+2
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('3') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+3
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('4') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+4
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('5') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+5
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('6') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+6
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('7') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+7
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('8') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+8
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('9') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+9
                        amount=amount+1
                    if ('10') == column[2]:
                        overall=overall+10
                        amount=amount+1
        total=overall/amount
```

Comment: Why all these `if` statements doing the same thing? Just convert the string into an integer and you'll avoid repeating the same code again and again.

Comment: I'm only in my second year of school and we haven't been taught much about coding (we focus more on ICT and theory) so I just went with what seemed easy. Thanks for the help, I'll try that

Comment: Ok. Can you show an extract of the csv?

Comment: Moreover, you have a division by 0 because amount is equal to 0, which means you have no corresponding entry in your csv. In that case, what value should the average take?

Comment: Okay, I don't know how to show an extract but I can describe it?

Comment: Take a look at my answer and tell me if it's ok

Comment: I ran it, and it came up with the no corresponding entry message. But the subject and difficulty I entered has four entries in the csv file

Comment: Maybe you're not using the same delimiter as the default values of `csv.reader`

Comment: Try to display `line` with a `print` in the loop and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: I created a 'sign into an existing account function' earlier, similar to how I created this one, and it worked just fine. I was thinking that maybe it isn't reading the numbers correctly as it can identify words (such as the subject name, or a username)

Comment: Can't you provide an example of csv file? Doesn't need to be the real data, just something where you don't have the expected result. See MCVE: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: I printed line, and it came out with the results for a hard chemistry quiz. But I had searched for an easy maths quiz

Comment: Oh also, my csv is comma delimited, thought I should mention that

Comment: If you print the line before the if statement, that's normal that it doesn't match your search. The important is to check that it is an iterable, its first field is subject, second field is difficulty, and third is score.

Comment: Either you do these tests seriously, or your provide your file, but now it's pointless trying to help you...

Comment: I am fine showing you the real data, it's not real/personal info, I just literally don't know how to show you it

Comment: Paste a few lines.

Comment: It's displayed in an excel spreadsheet, but saved as a csv. So it would look something like this: maths, easy, 5, Sin37 (subject, difficulty, score out of ten, username)

Comment: Oh, maybe because of spaces after commas then

Comment: Hang on, got the whole file here, I put it into word pad instead

Comment: Subject,Difficulty,Score,Username
Maths,easy,5,Sin37
Maths,easy,0,Sin37
Maths,hard,4,Sin37
Maths,hard,2,Sin37
Maths,easy,9,La 14
Literature,hard,9,La 14
Biology,medium,9,La 14
Language,hard,9,La 14
Chemistry,hard,10,La 14

Comment: There are no spaces now, and it still doesn't work

Comment: Works well for me

Comment: I created a file with this data (except that I put it on different lines), and tried with "Maths" and "easy", I got "4.666667"

Comment: Are you using python 3?

Comment: Of course. As you can notice, I wrote `print` as a function, which was not the case in Python 2

Comment: Is there any reason you can think of as to why mine wouldn't work? My teacher told me once that python sometimes has trouble when you've made so many errors within a function and not started over, is that true? Sorry if this is a stupid question I'm literally 13 and it's 10pm here and I'm getting very frustrated

Comment: Add `print(line)` at the beginning of the loop and show me one line of the output. Plus, don't get frustrated, it doesn't solve problems. Midnight here :)

Comment: Thank you for helping :). Okay so now it has printed off the whole csv, with the error message at the end? ['Subject', 'Difficulty', 'Score', 'Username']
['Maths', 'easy', '5', 'Sin37']
['Maths', 'easy', '0', 'Sin37']
['Maths', 'hard', '4', 'Sin37']
['Maths', 'hard', '2', 'Sin37']
['Maths', 'easy', '9', 'La 14']
['Literature', 'hard', '9', 'La 14']
['Biology', 'medium', '9', 'La 14']
['Language', 'hard', '9', 'La 14']
['Chemistry', 'hard', '10', 'La 14']
No entry corresponding to this subject and difficulty

Comment: That's the output I expect. You can remove the `print` statement. Now try it with "Maths" and "easy", and be careful you write exactly that, with the capital letter, no typo, etc. It should work, really

Comment: It worked, and with all the other quizzes, Jesus Christ, thank you so much :)

Comment: ..... that's a stupid error, isn't it? :D

Comment: Anyway, you can mark my answer as accepted to that the topic will be showed as having an answer

Comment: I can't believe I've been stuck here for hours over a capital m smh... Again, thank you.

Comment: Hope it taught you a lesson. Moreover, you've also learnt that repetitive code is never good, take time to understand the changed I've made, if it's not already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a division by 0 because no corresponding entry is found, therefore `amount` is never incremented, so you should handle that case.
Moreover, your code can be simplified a lot, it is very repetitive.

I can't test since you didn't provide an example of csv file, but tell me if you're happy with this:

```
def quizReport():
    overall = 0
    amount = 0
    subjectInput=input("\nPlease enter the subject name of the quiz(zes) you wish to view: ")
    difficultyInput=input("Please enter the difficulty level of the quiz(zes) you wish to view: ")

    with open ('reportForFergusTwo.csv') as quizzReport:
        quizReportReader=csv.reader(quizzReport)
        for line in quizReportReader:
            if subjectInput == line[0].strip() and difficultyInput == line[1].strip():
                amount += 1
                overall += int(line[2])

        if amount == 0:
            print("No entry corresponding to this subject and difficulty")
        else:
            avg_score = overall / amount
            print("Average score: %f" % avg_score)
```

---

EDIT: if the expected data is not found, you're probably not reading the csv correctly. Display `line` with `print` in the loop to make sure it is what you expect.

One possible reason could be the delimiters: csv is sometimes separated with comma, sometimes with semicolon. This is an optional parameter of `csv.reader`.

---

EDIT: added `strip()` in my code in case there are spaces following the commas in the csv.